# argv to get hex data in order to decrypt. String to unsigned char

Tags: c, string, casting, unsigned-char

I'm coding a program which should get a key and an encrypted data ( unsigned char HEXs) in order to return the decrypted info.
My code is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "aes.h"
int main(int argc, unsigned char * argv[])
{
    int i=1;
    //unsigned char ptext[16] = "Attack at down!";
    unsigned char ptext[16]={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x03,0x15,0x02,0x01,0x00,0x19};
    //    unsigned char ctext[16]={0x9b,0x54,0xd4,0x9e,0xdc,0x96,0x69,0x30,0xf7,0xc5,0xd4,0x25,0x39,0x77,0xbe,0xb8};
    //unsigned char ctext[16]={0x54,0x9b,0x9e,0xd4,0x96,0xdc,0x30,0x69,0xc5,0xf7,0x25,0xd4,0x77,0x39,0xb8,0xbe};
    //unsigned char ctext[16]={0x51,0x0e,0xa4,0x12,0xa0,0x6f,0xdd,0x4e,0x4f,0x17,0x7c,0xe3,0x9d,0x0e,0x28,0xea};    
    unsigned char ctext[16]={0x2E,0x45,0x58,0x36,0xA8,0xAC,0x79,0x7E,0xC4,0xDF,0x51,0xDB,0xC4,0x88,0x28,0xC0};

    unsigned char key[KEY_128];
    //unsigned char key[KEY_128] ={0x0f,0x15,0x71,0xc9,0x47,0xd9,0xe8,0xf3,0x0f,0x15,0x71,0xc9,0x47,0xd9,0xe8,0xf3};
    unsigned char decptext[16];
    unsigned char test=0xFF;

    //gcc main.c aes.c -o decripter
    //sh decripter key encrypted --> return (decrypted)
    printf("\n test %x",test);       
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        //How can I pass what I get from argv to the key unsigned char?? 
        key[i]=argv[i+1];
        printf("Key pos %d data->%s",i,key[i]);
    }  

    aes_ctx_t *ctx;

    init_aes();
    ctx = aes_alloc_ctx(key, sizeof(key));

    //Encrypted
    //aes_encrypt(ctx, ptext, ctext);
    //    printf("%s",ctext);

    aes_decrypt(ctx,ctext,decptext);
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        printf("\n Decrypted data, position in array-> %d data->  %x \n",i, decptext[i]);

    aes_free_ctx(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

This time I only tried to get the Key. As you can see, I tried also to use unsigned char *argv[] because I thought that I'd get an unsigned char but the only way to print what I get from argv is with %s, so it's a string and I can't find the way to pass it to unsigned char key[16] (128 bits = 16*8bit per HEX).
To execute the program I do it like this:

```
./prueba 0x0f 0x15 0x71 0xc9 0x47 0xd9 0xe8 0xf3 0x0f 0x15 0x71 0xc9 0x47 0xd9 0xe8 0xf3
```

Any help will be really welcome.

Thanks.

I'm trying with your code like this and it works perfect THX ALL:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, unsigned char * argv[])
{
unsigned int aes_uint[16];
unsigned int cipher_uint[16];

int comerce;

uint8_t aes_data[16];
uint8_t ciphertext[16];
char temp[16][3]; // For 5 hex values if you want more char temp[10][5] for 10 values
char temp2[16][3]; // For 5 hex values if you want more char temp[10][5] for 10 values

char tempcomerce[2][3]; // For 5 hex values if you want more char temp[10][5] for 10 values

int i,j,k,c;

 for(i=0,c=0;argv[1][i];i++,c++){         // To parse the input argument to diff hex values
            for(j=i,k=0; j<(i+2) ;j++,k++){
            temp[c][k]=argv[1][j];
            }
            i=j-1;
            temp[c][k] = '\0';
    }

    for(i=0;i<c;i++) // where c stores the number hex values you have passed through argument
    {
            sscanf(temp[i],"%x",&aes_uint[i]);
            aes_data[i] = (unsigned char)aes_uint[i];
            printf("AES pos %d data->%x\n",i,aes_data[i]);
    }

    for(i=0,c=0;argv[2][i];i++,c++){         // To parse the input argument to diff hex values
            for(j=i,k=0; j<(i+2) ;j++,k++){
            temp2[c][k]=argv[2][j];
            }
            i=j-1;
            temp2[c][k] = '\0';
    }

    for(i=0;i<c;i++) // where c stores the number hex values you have passed through argument
    {
            sscanf(temp2[i],"%x",&cipher_uint[i]);
            ciphertext[i] = (unsigned char)cipher_uint[i];
            printf("Cipther pos %d data->%x\n",i,ciphertext[i]);
    }

    sscanf(argv[3],"%d",&comerce);
    printf("Comerce-->%d\n",comerce );



    // do your stuff        


return 0;
}
```

I introduce:

```
./prueba 52871D6B9D600046D721C97990EF42FA 52871D6B9D600046D720D47390EE42BC 56748
```

I get:

```
    AES pos 0 data->52
AES pos 1 data->87
AES pos 2 data->1d
AES pos 3 data->6b
AES pos 4 data->9d
AES pos 5 data->60
AES pos 6 data->0
AES pos 7 data->46
AES pos 8 data->d7
AES pos 9 data->21
AES pos 10 data->c9
AES pos 11 data->79
AES pos 12 data->90
AES pos 13 data->ef
AES pos 14 data->42
AES pos 15 data->fa
Cipther pos 0 data->52
Cipther pos 1 data->87
Cipther pos 2 data->1d
Cipther pos 3 data->6b
Cipther pos 4 data->9d
Cipther pos 5 data->60
Cipther pos 6 data->0
Cipther pos 7 data->46
Cipther pos 8 data->d7
Cipther pos 9 data->20
Cipther pos 10 data->d4
Cipther pos 11 data->73
Cipther pos 12 data->90
Cipther pos 13 data->ee
Cipther pos 14 data->42
Cipther pos 15 data->bc
Comerce-->56748
```

Iván Gómez

Comment: If you are passing multiple arguments, use respective arguments to parse it! I think you are parsing first arguments two time. Check the output of first and second arguments. It is same! After parsing first argument parse the second one!

Comment: for(i=0,c=0;argv[2][i];i++,c++){ 
            for(j=i,k=0; j<(i+2) ;j++,k++){
            temp[c][k]=argv[2][j]; // note this. You have argv[1][j]

Comment: I have edited your solution try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sscanf`-

```
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        //key[i]=argv[i+1]; 
        sscanf(argv[i+1],"%x",&key[i]); // It will work for you!

        printf("Key pos %d data->%u",i,key[i]);
    }
```

But when you use `%x` in `sscanf`, it needs third argument as a type of `unsigned int`! But `key[KEY_128];` is `unsigned char`,  So declare `key[KEY_128];` as `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned char`!

**Edit**:
Declare a another array of type `unsigned int` and convert the string to `unsigned int` and again convert back to `unsigned char`. Try this-

```
unsigned char key[KEY_128];
unsigned int key_uint[KEY_128];
// your stuff

for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
        //key[i]=argv[i+1]; 
        sscanf(argv[i+1],"%x",&key_uint[i]);
        key[i] = (unsigned char)key_uint[i];
        printf("Key pos %d data->%u",i,key[i]);
}
```

**Parsing:** if you pass HEX values as single argument.

```
    unsigned char key[KEY_128];
    unsigned int key_uint[KEY_128];
    char temp[5][5]; // For 5 hex values if you want more char temp[10][5] for 10 values
    int i,j,k,c;

    for(i=0,c=0;argv[1][i];i++,c++){         // To parse the input argument to diff hex values
            for(j=i,k=0; j<(i+4) ;j++,k++){
            temp[c][k]=argv[1][j];
            }
            i=j-1;
            temp[c][k] = '\0';
    }

    // do your stuff        

    for(i=0;i<c;i++) // where c stores the number hex values you have passed through argument
    {
            sscanf(temp[i],"%x",&key_uint[i]);
            key[i] = (unsigned char)key_uint[i];
            printf("Key pos %d data->%u\n",i,key[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I use the key as unsigned char because the decrypt and encrypt function needs that data type. I'm going to try your snippets. Thanks you very much

Comment: Seems interesting. I'm going to try it right now. Thanks again.

Comment: It works perfectly. Do you know if it's easy to receive different parameters, now I'm receiving HEX, but could I also get a String as last parameter?

Comment: @user1688663 I think you are already passing string, and you are converting it to hex! you mean hex data to string conversion?

Comment: I mean, when I call the program for example with ./test 0x01 0xFF... but, if I try for example all together as one ./test 0x010xFF... I should parse it and it would be an string ( as now, but before argv[1] was 0x01 and now it would be only 0, wouldn't it? So I should parse counting and saving from argv[1] to argv[4] into a char temp[4], use sscanf to store it in the key_uint and after that cast it to key as I did before? I fail so hard doing those things and I don't know how to learn to handle those cases. Thanks

Comment: @Fulgor3 Try my new edit! Is Above solution is working for ` ./test 0x010xFF...`?

Comment: I tried this and didn't work me well and I have to think it a bit to adapt it, so much values in the for condition for me jeje. But the idea is really well focused. Thx!!! Now the HEX I pass in argv is without the 0x at the beginning, so 52871D6B9D600046D721C97990EF42FA like this.
Fixes added at the end of my post. Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

I think sscanf is your best bet. Also, you don't need to have "unsigned char" argv, as you always get & expect strings in argument. Hope below code sample helps you.

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
    if (sscan(argv[i+1], "%x", &key[i]) != 1) {
        // throw error
    }

    printf("Key pos %d data->%s",i,key[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite:

if (sscan(argv[i+1], "%x", &key[i]) != 1) {

To:

if (sscan(argv[1][i], "%x", &key[i]) != 1) {

Comment: Could you offer some explanation as to why the OP should rewrite that line of code?